# sidebar layout in ember-paper not working

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-paper

I'm trying to use [ember-paper](http://miguelcobain.github.io/) in my [ember](http://emberjs.com/) app but i can't float content to the right.

> Example

[image]

> What I want to achieve (from ember-paper official website)

[image]

> My code

**application.hbs**

```
{{#paper-nav-container}}
  {{#paper-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left site-sidenav md-whiteframe-z2" locked-open="gt-sm"}}
    {{#paper-toolbar}}
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <div class="logo">
          <strong>Paper</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/paper-toolbar}}

    {{#paper-content}}
      {{#paper-list}}
        {{#paper-item action=(transition-to "employees.list")}}Introduction{{/paper-item}}
        {{#paper-item action=(transition-to "index")}}Another link{{/paper-item}}
      {{/paper-list}}
    {{/paper-content}}
  {{/paper-sidenav}}

  <div layout="column" tabindex="-1" role="main" flex>
    {{#paper-toolbar}}
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <span class="md-breadcrumb-page">Title</span>
      </div>
    {{/paper-toolbar}}

    {{#paper-content class="md-padding"}}
      {{outlet}}
    {{/paper-content}}
  </div>
{{/paper-nav-container}}
```

How can I float sidebar to the left? I have no errors in console, and it was a straight copy-paste from [official guide](http://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-paper/release-0-2/#/sidenav)

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @PaulFournel nope :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is using the `display:flex` probably thats not supported in your browser http://caniuse.com/#search=flex ? provided you copy pasted the entire CSS required.

Comment: it is supported though..i'm out of ideas